# How to change the value of dirty_writeback_centisecs?

Tags: 16.04, power-management, xfce, powertop

I would like to change the value of *dirty_writeback_centisecs*. After seeing the Tunables in Powertop, there seems to be a problem with the value which is 6000 which is considered to be bad by Powertop. It echoes the value to 1500. However, the change is not persistent.

I tried..

Setting `vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=1500` in the **/etc/sysctl.conf**
and also `sys.vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=1500` neither did work. Also, in **/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf** which too didn't work.

The value is still 6000 on restart.

Comment: `vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 1500` in `sysctl.conf` should have been enough to make the change permanent (and you don't need to even reboot if you run `sudo sysctl -p` after modifying that file). If that doesn't work, then you must be missing permission errors or some another software is running that sets different value for you.

Answer (score 3):

To make these settings *permanent*, on Debian you have to add these lines into `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
   vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 1500
   vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 1500
```

But if you have installed and enabled the [`tlp`](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) service for better power-management, then the above configurations are ignored, and you have to uncomment the following lines in `/etc/defaults/tlp`:

```
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=15
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting

```
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

in /etc/rc.local

and then do

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

to make it run at boot.

As an example, because of way too much RAM and good power-supply redundant security and reliability in a VPS somewhere, my /etc/rc.local currently has this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo 24 > /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
echo 99 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
echo 12000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
echo 12000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs

(/bin/sleep 60 && /sbin/dhclient -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf -6 &)
exit 0
```

but I only recommend that to gain disk-IO if you have enough RAM and CPU.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu may not enable executing `/etc/rc.local` by default. To enable that, you may have to run `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` once after installing the operating system. That's supposed to be enabled automatically but sometimes it seems to fail.

Comment: In lastest Ubuntu it is not so easy to enable rc-local service - you need to modify the service file - add `WantedBy=multi-user.target` into the `[Install]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service` file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, after changing the parameters in /etc/sysctl.conf with root privilege and saving and closing the file, `sudo sysctl -p` command will effect the change. Regards

Comment: No, that didn't work